# CMake build of LLVM clang fails with "Unexpected failure executing llvm-build: Traceback (...) import llvmbuild"

Tags: python, build, llvm, clang

I want to build LLVM clang compiler, but CMake ends up with the following error message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:256 (message):
  Unexpected failure executing llvm-build: Traceback (most recent call
last):

    File "C:/.../llvm/utils/llvm-build/llvm-build", line 3, in
<module>
      import llvmbuild
    File "C:\...\llvm\utils\llvm-build\llvmbuild\__init__.py",
line 1, in
<module>
      from main import main

  ImportError: No module named main


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I've got all needed tools installed.

- OS: Windows 7 x64
- Python: 3.2.2 (x86-64)
- GnuWin32: 0.6.3

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've found the solution.

I've just installed another version of **Python: 2.x** (2.72), (still x86-64)

Comment: I have run into this problem in [Gentoo GNU/Linux](http://www.gentoo.org/) as well. At this writing, the latest stable ebuild (Gentoo equivalent of a package or port) seems to use whatever Python interpreter is selected as the system default. Thus it will fail with this error if Python 3 is the default, even if Python 2 is installed at the same time.

I was able to work around this simply by setting Python 2 as the default (e.g. `eselect python set python2.7`).