# Does CMAKE support Python 3?

Tags: python, cmake, llvm, clang

I'm attempting to build Clang on Windows 7 using CMAKE.

I've performed the following steps; as specified in [this guide](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html). The guide is wrong in one aspect: Python **is** required and without it, cmake returns an error. I am assuming that since cmake supports Visual Studio 11, and I don't have VS10 installed, it's acceptable to substitute one for the other. It doesn't seem reasonable that doing this would produce the error I'm seeing.

I've installed Python 3.3 with all the default options using the Windows x86 installer from [this page](http://www.python.org/download/).

With Python 3.3 installed and on path, `cmake -G "Visual Studio 11" ..\llvm` returns the following error:

```
D:\Code\build>cmake -G "Visual Studio 11" ..\llvm
<snip>
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Python33/python.exe (found version "3.3.2")
-- Constructing LLVMBuild project information
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:308 (message):
  Unexpected failure executing llvm-build: Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "D:/Code/llvm/utils/llvm-build/llvm-build", line 3, in <module>
      import llvmbuild
    File "D:\Code\llvm\utils\llvm-build\llvmbuild\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
      from main import main

  ImportError: No module named 'main'


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

D:\Code\build>
```

What the? Does this indicate a compatibility problem between python 2.x and python 3.x, or something else? I can't find any clear information indicating whether cmake supports python 3.x, but I can't find anything that says it doesn't either. I'd prefer not to have two incompatible versions of python on my machine if at all possible.

**edit:** Ah. Seems [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017376/cmake-build-of-llvm-clang-fails-with-unexpected-failure-executing-llvm-build-t) asks the same thing, and seems to indicate that python 3.x is **not** supported. I'll post this as an answer if experimenting proves that fact. D'oh!

Comment: Instead of asking on the lazyweb, I would have checked the bug reports. I'm sure there is a feature request for Python 3 support already.

Comment: There are a couple that point this out in an obtuse sort of way, but nothing obvious. In any case, I was guessing that this was the problem; since I happened to know that python 2.x and python 3.x are not compatible; there's no reason to assume that the average novice would. The real question is "what does this error message mean?" - since it doesn't give any indication of what the **actual problem** is - as usual for open-source projects.

Answer (score 2):

It's not CMake, it's the `llvm-build` tool which is used as part of the CMake configuration process for LLVM. It lives in `utils/llvm-build` and reads `LLVMBuild.txt` files. At this time, `llvm-build` does not support Python 3.x

This is the case for most major LLVM Python-based tools, like the `lit` test runner.

FWIW, CMake itself doesn't depend on Python so it doesn't care about the installed Python version.